# How use tm_yday in Qt

Tags: c++, qt

I need get number of days since 1 January.
But I dont know how to use tm_yday(how use this function)!
Then i need convert it to Qstring.How can I do this?
Please give code or example how to do this.
Thank you.

Comment: `tm_yday` is not a function, it is a member of `struct tm` in Posix. I am not sure what does it have to do with Qt.

Comment: I want get number of days .How can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

Use `mktime`:

```
#include <time.h>
#include <QString>

tm timeinfo;
timeinfo.tm_year = year - 1900;
timeinfo.tm_mon = month - 1;
timeinfo.tm_mday = day;
mktime(&timeinfo);
int yday = timeinfo.tm_yday;
QString strday = QString("%1").arg(yday);
```